# MongoDB - Aggregate $match on ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Owner',{
    username: String,
    blocks: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Block'},
});
```

I'm trying to run a query to see if Owner has a reference to Block's id. Owner has an array of ObjectIds. When I run `db.owners.aggregate({$match: {username: 'example'}},{$unwind: "$blocks"},{$project: { _id : 1,blocks: 1}})` it returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550d9dc64d9dc3d026fadfc7"), "blocks" : ObjectId("550dc117dc9605ab27070af7") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550d9dc64d9dc3d026fadfc7"), "blocks" : ObjectId("550dc123dc9605ab27070af8") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550d9dc64d9dc3d026fadfc7"), "blocks" : ObjectId("550dc12edc9605ab27070af9") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550d9dc64d9dc3d026fadfc7"), "blocks" : ObjectId("550dc157dc9605ab27070afa") }
```

How can I match the block id? I've tried `db.publishers.aggregate({$match: {username: 'example'}},{$unwind: "$blocks"},{$project: { _id : 1,blocks: 1}},{$match : {"blocks._id" : '550dc157dc9605ab27070afa'}})` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you don't need aggreation for that, you can use a simple `find()` or `findOne()` query:

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = Mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

Owner.findOne({ username: 'example', blocks: new ObjectId('550dc157dc9605ab27070afa') }, function (err, owner) {
   ...
});
```

Comment: That works too! BUT I had to reference it (both with `.aggregation` and `.find`) as ObjectId('550dc157dc9605ab27070afa'). I discovered that after finding this link https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1399. Not sure why I was using aggregation framework. I had been using it on something that had subdocuments.

Comment: Nice! I thought Mongoose was clever enough to convert the string automatically to an ObjectId when the field references an other model, but looks like not. I modified the code now to use `new ObjectId()` on the string.

Comment: This is a good alternative for your use-case, but it does not specifically answer the question of matching with an ObjectId in aggregate, which if possible - would be very helpful.

Comment: @jordan Thanks very much for providing that link :)

Answer (score 1):

that does not work right now with versions > 3.8.31
i've wasted countless hours on that one, should have tested the earlier mayor sooner...