# How to use aggregrate in mongodb to $match _id

Tags: mongodb

Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("560c24b853b558856ef193a3"),
    "name" : "Karl Morrison",
    "pic" : "",
    "language" : ObjectId("560c24b853b558856ef193a2"),
    "cell" : 1,
    "local" : {
        "email" : "karl.morrison@instanty.se",
        "password" : "12345"
    },
    "sessions" : [
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("560c24b853b558856ef193a5")
        }
    ]
}
```

This works:

```
yield new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                users.col.aggregate([
                        {
                            $match: {
                                'name': 'Karl Morrison'
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    function (err, res) {
                        console.log('err ' + err);
                        console.log('res ' + JSON.stringify(res)); // <-- echos the object retrieved
                        if (err === null)
                            resolve(res);
                        reject(err);
                    });
            });
```

This does not work:

```
yield new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                users.col.aggregate([
                        {
                            $match: {
                                '_id': '560c24b853b558856ef193a3' // <-- _id of the user
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    function (err, res) {
                        console.log('err ' + err);
                        console.log('res ' + JSON.stringify(res));
                        if (err === null)
                            resolve(res);
                        reject(err);
                    });
            });
```

The `.col` access the native mongodb object (using co-monk otherwise). So I'm doing it manually. This however isn't working. I suspect I am not casting the id hexstring to an ObjectId. No matter what I try nothing works.

Comment: The `_id` needs to be an `ObjectId`. Monk cannot cast the type for you from a string when used with `.aggregate()`, so you need to cast the type yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - Aggregate $match on ObjectId](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187459/mongodb-aggregate-match-on-objectid). Basic same reason which is "cast it yourself", as both frameworks use similar code for auto-casting, but none of it applies to `.aggregate()`.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Indeed it is, thank you, been looking for ages (didn't find it due to mongoose probably)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
const User = mongoose.model('User')

User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { _id: ObjectId('560c24b853b558856ef193a3') }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 17):

Try this

```
const User = require('User')
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('560c24b853b558856ef193a3') }
  }
])
```

Comment: Why 'new' keyword here? Is there not a better way to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with $oid for older Mongos versions.

`{ $match: { '_id' : {"$oid": '560c24b853b558856ef193a3' }    } }`

Greetings.

Answer (score -5):

```
const User = mongoose.model('User')
User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('id') }
  }
])
```

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of the correct way of doing this?