# Express Route with /:id input returns empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to have my API take an `id` as input and return results from mongoDB according to the `id` given.

My example collection looks like this:

```
id: 1 {
   count: 5
}
id: 2 {
   count: 10
}
```

My mongoose Schemas looks like this:

```
var tripSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    count: Number
},
    {collection: 'test'}
);
```

And I created another file for this route, where I think the error lies in:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/trips/:id', function(req,res) {
        console.log(req.params.id); // Does print the ID correctly
            var aggr = Trip.aggregate([
                {   "$match": {
                        "_id": {
                            "$eq": req.params.id
                        }
                     }
                },
                {
                "$project": {
                    "_id"  : 1,
                    "count": "$count"
                }
            }
            ])
            aggr.options = { allowDiskUse: true };
            aggr.exec(function(err, stations){
            if(err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(stations); 
        });
    });
}
```

Now using postman I try to `GET` `/trips/72`, but this results in an empty array `[]`, there is an entry in the DB for `_id` 72 with a corresponding count just like above. My question is if this is the correct approach and what I am doing wrong here.

--Update:
There seems to be something wrong with either the `match` stage or the whole `aggregation`. I opted for mongoose's `findById`, and with this it works now:

```
    Trip.findById(req.params.id, function (err, doc){
      res.json(doc);
    });
```

Comment: Try `parseInt(req.params.id)` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877064/how-to-use-aggregrate-in-mongodb-to-match-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.params.id` returns your id in String form, while I think in aggregate `match` section you need to pass it as ObjectId. So, you should convert it to ObjectId:

```
$match: { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }
```

Comment: This results for me in "Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters" error.

Comment: Please `console.log(req.params.id)` and check that it contains a valid id value.

Comment: Yes it prints '72' when called like this: `trips/72`. 72 is also a valid "_id" in the mongoDB collection, but just 72, not sorrounded with ObjectID("72"). This might be the cause.

Comment: Are you using custom values for `_id`? because 72 is not a valid object id and so doing `ObjectId()` on it will always throw an error.

Comment: Yes I defined the _id's myself, this is the cause.

Comment: ok. In that case if you are storing your _id's as strings you can simply use `match: { _id: req.params.id }` or if you are storing _id's as numbers then you can use `match: { _id: parseInt(req.params.id) }`.