# Translate MongoDB shell query to js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a problem with rewriting MongoDB shell query to JavaScript.

This is a shell query that works (it returns expected object):

```
db.decks.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: ObjectId('605072934f19160027b0c1a9')}},
    {
        $lookup: {
            "from": "cards",
            "localField": "cards",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "cards"
        }
    }
])
```

Now I try to write it in my JS code like that:

```
const deck = await Deck.aggregate([
            {$match: {"_id": `ObjectId(${id})`}},
            {
                $lookup: {
                    "from": "cards",
                    "localField": "cards",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "cards"
                }
            }
        ])
```

but `$match` does not match anything. I tried various variations of quotes. With and without `ObjectId`. I can't see what is wrong in here. `Deck` is proper model (`await Deck.findById(id)` works fine).

Comment: I think someone has the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877064/how-to-use-aggregrate-in-mongodb-to-match-id/43199139

Comment: Thanks, @HoàngTrung, I cannot found this question before. It helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're stringifying the `ObjectId` function.
Try this:

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');

const itemID = <item id>;

const deck = await Deck.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "_id": new mongo.ObjectID(itemID) }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            "from": "cards",
            "localField": "cards",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "cards"
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You were right with stringify of ObjectID. `new mongo.Types.ObjectId(id)` is the correct answer.