# How to filter aggregation pipeline by specific ids

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Given this data:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "jim",
},
{
  "_id": 2,
  "name": "bob",
},
{
  "_id": 3,
  "name": "bill",
},
{
  "_id": 4,
  "name": "bob",
}
```

I have a simple aggregation pipeline to retrieve documents with the name `bob`:

```
[
    { "$match": { "name": "bob" } }
]
```

However, I also have an array of ids (e.g. `[1, 2]`) that I want to use to filter the documents (either before or after the `$match` query runs). So the final result of the above aggregation pipeline should be:

```
{
  "_id": 2,
  "name": "bob",
}
```

Usually I would do this with a query like `{ "_id": { "$in": [1, 2] } }`, however having been through the MongoDB docs it appears the aggregation operations are different from regular aggregation operations, and I can't seem to find an aggregate that can achieve this (neither in the docs nor online).

Comment: { "$match": { "name": "bob" , "_id": { "$in": [1, 2] }} }

Comment: As you can see here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/gWLMHPHYEYy

Comment: I was trying to run them as separate queries

Comment: May help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877064/how-to-use-aggregrate-in-mongodb-to-match-id